# Implications of using non-unicode library with a unicode-built application

Tags: windows, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I would like to use a non-unicode library from my unicode-built MFC application. However, I'm not sure whether there is a possibility of occurring events such as unintended memory allocations, string handling inside the non-unicode library.

Please explain any implications or provide a resource page.

Comment: You want to build a library with your application?  Is your application a compiler/linker?  Or perhaps you mean that you want to load a non-unicode library from your unicode application?

Comment: I meant that I need to load a non-unicode library from my unicode application. I need to understand the behavior of such library under unicode context. Any ideas pls.

Comment: Does the non-unicode library also use MFC?

Comment: No, this library does not use any visual c++ libraries/frameworks. however, this library is linked with several other non-unicode libraries. Each of these libraries written from the scratch and no popular frameworks are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not an application is Unicode is a compile-time, not a run-time, distinction - there is no inherent reason why a Unicode executable can't load an ANSI DLL.  If the application and DLL both used MFC they would be linked to different MFC runtimes, which could cause problems, but as that isn't the case you should be fine.

Where you need to take care is to ensure that any string data transferred between the DLL and the application are interpreted consistently.  Mostly this just means converting between ANSI and Unicode as necessary, and Windows provides API functions which allow you to do this easily enough.

You should, however, check the header files for any data types that are interpreted differently when compiling for Unicode than when compiling for ANSI.  For example, if one of the DLL functions was declared as

```
DWORD process_string(TCHAR * string)
```

then the non-unicode library would interpret TCHAR as char, but your application would interpret it as wchar_t, hiding the fact that you need to convert the string to ANSI before calling the function.

Comment: @ktai, if you see this, you can post a new question linking to this one, or email me.  But basically if the headers are incompatible you can either make a copy and fix them, or just use casting, e.g., `process_string((TCHAR *)"hello")` (but make sure you include a comment to explain *why* you're casting or it will look like a bug).